# Amazon SES で SPF は機能しますか？

Tags: amazon-ses

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/ses/latest/dg/send-email-authentication-spf.html

Amazon SES を使う場合の SPF の設定で

```
"v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all"
```

とかけってあるんですが
これって mail.example.co.jp からのメールだと区別するSMTPサーバーの情報がどこにもないので
確かに送信はできると思うんですが
SES を使ってる他の誰かに送信先を偽装されてしまう気がします

認識間違っていますか？

独自のSMTP用のEIPをとってそのアドレスをメールドメインMXレコードを結びつけて
Route53 と連動した設定みたいなのは必要ないんでしょうか？

Comment: さすがに From ヘッダや envelope from は偽装できないよう、制限はあるかと思いますが。

Comment: 直接 AWS のサポートに問い合わせることも検討してみてください。 https://aws.amazon.com/jp/premiumsupport/tech-support-guidelines/